# Custom language code with qtranslate

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

Does anybody know if I can modify the custom language code in qTranslate...

I want to modify the 2 letter code with the name of the language like this:
www.domain.com/en -> www.domain.com/english

For 5 different languages...

Can it be done and how?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect you can't do this in the database.  There are various places in the qTranslate code that assume a two-letter language code, such as:

```
if (preg_match("#^<!--:([a-z]{2})-->$#ism", $block, $matches)) {
```

in the `qtrans_split` function in `qtranslate_core.php`.

You may be able to get the result you want by changing your URL mappings (possibly in your `.htaccess` file), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah this can be achieved through URL mapping. Each language slug would add different query string like:
domain/english  &lang=en_US
domain/german  &lang=de